# How to diagnose why a Sinatra app is throwing NotFound in production but not in development?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, puma, airbrake

I have a Sinatra app in production (running with Puma) that includes a not_found handler:

```
module MyApp
  class Server
    not_found do
      [404, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, ['{"error":"not found"}']]
    end
  end
end
```

In development, this does what I expect and on missing pages I see a 404 with a JSON error message. However, in production I'm seeing a NotFound exception which triggers an Airbrake alert.

The stack trace is long, but the top line points here:

```
/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1021 in "route_missing"
```

Which is here:
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1021 ,which does:

```
def route_missing
  if @app
    forward
  else
    raise NotFound
  end
end
```

The comments in the Sinatra source say that the error is forwarded if your app is not middleware, otherwise it is raised. Yet somehow my expectation would be that my not_found handler should be called instead. It is being called in development. How can I best debug why it isn't in production?

Comment: the source actually seems to suggest it fowards "*when running as middleware*". You could inherit from `Base` and override.